# Grails: Do addTo* and removeFrom* require a call to save?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

In the docs [some examples](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html) have a call to `save` whereas [some others](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html) do not. I'm assuming that `addTo*` needs the call to `save` whereas `removeFrom*` doesn't. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither needs a call to `save()` in most contexts. What you're seeing in the "[some examples](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html)" link is a save to the main domain object `Author`, which gets persisted first, and then the other properties will make it in the database with a proper `id` to link back to. For example, these two snippets are equivalent as far as persistence is concerned:

```
def a = new Author(name: "Stephen King")
         .addToFiction(fictBook)
         .addToNonFiction(nonFictBook)
         .save()
```

and

```
def a = new Author(name: "Stephen King").save()
a.addToFiction(fictBook)
a.addToNonFiction(nonFictBook)
```

Sometimes, a `save(flush:true)` operation is needed if you're after an `id` for further dependent operations, otherwise it is not necessary.

To test, open two browsers, on one do your app clicking, on the other watch your `.../dbconsole` - persistence is prompt without the need for explicit saving.